Real character implies isotypic subspace has real basis?
Let $ \rho: G \to GL(n,\mathbb{C}) $ be an irreducible complex representation of $ G $. Let $ \chi_\rho $ be the character of $ \rho $. Let $ \rho^{\otimes k} $ be the $ k $ tensor power of the representation $ \rho $. Let $ \mu:= \langle \chi_\rho, \chi_\rho^k \rangle $ be the multiplicity of the irrep $ \rho $ in $ \rho^{\otimes k} $.
If $ \rho $ is a real representation (Frobenius-Schur indicator +1) then there should exist some vectors $ v_{ij} , 1 \leq i \leq n , 1 \leq j \leq \mu $ such that the $ v_{ij} $ span the $ \rho $ isotypic subspace of $ \rho^{\otimes k} $ and, moreover, all the $ v_{ij} \in (\mathbb{R}^n)^{\otimes k} $
For a $ \rho $ that cannot be a real representation, but $ \chi_\rho $ is still real (Frobenius-Schur indicator -1), is something similar true? That is, can we still find $ v_{ij} $ that span the $ \rho $ isotypic subspace of $ \rho^{\otimes k} $ and that moreover have the property $ v_{ij} \in (\mathbb{R}^n)^{\otimes k} $?

@LukasHeger For $k=1$ the question is asking if $\Bbb C^n$ has a basis of vectors from $\Bbb R^n$, which is clearly true, no? I am wondering, though, if OP intends the spans of ${v_{ij}\mid 1\le i\le n}$ as $j$ varies to be the summands of an internal direct sum decomposition of said isotypic component.
